# How to sort Fuzzysearch results in StrapiCms?

Tags: sorting, strapi, fuzzy-search

The fuzzysearch plugin is active in Strapicms, and I receive results when I perform searches on specific contents. However, I want to retrieve these results in the order that I desire.
To achieve this, I made adjustments to the fuzzysortOptions in the plugin.js file in Strapi.
To test these adjustments, I trigger fuzzysearch with queries in Postman, but I couldn’t make it work as I wanted.

The desired outcome is that when I perform a search with the keyword ‘test,’ it should bring me the results with ‘isCompleted’ fields set to false first, followed by those set to true. For both false and true cases, they should be further sorted within their groups based on the ‘deadline’ field for events (sorted in descending order) and the ‘endDate’ field for jobs (sorted in descending order
Below, I am sharing the fuzzysearch configuration in the plugin.js file and the query I use to trigger it in Postman.
I would greatly appreciate any help from those who have ideas on this matter.
config :

```
"fuzzy-search": {
  enabled: true,
  config: {
    contentTypes: [
      {
        uid: "api::event.event",
        modelName: "event",
        fuzzysortOptions: {
          characterLimit: 100,
          threshold: -1000,
          limit: 90,
          keys: [
            {
              name: "title",
              weight: 200,
            },
            {
              name: "isCompleted",
              weight: 100,
              direction: 'asc',
            },
            {
              name: "deadline",
              weight: 99,
              direction: 'desc',
            },
          ],
        },
      },
      {
        uid: "api::job.job",
        modelName: "job",
        transliterate: false,
        fuzzysortOptions: {
          characterLimit: 100,
          threshold: -1000,
          limit: 90,
          keys: [
            {
              name: "title",
              weight: 200,
            },
            {
              name: "isCompleted",
              weight: 100,
              direction: 'asc',
            },
            {
              name: "endDate",
              weight: 99,
              direction: 'desc',
            },
          ],
        },
      },
      {
        uid: "api::blog.blog",
        modelName: "blog",
        fuzzysortOptions: {
          characterLimit: 100,
          threshold: -1000,
          limit: 90,
          keys: [
            {
              name: "title",
              weight: 200,
            },
            {
              name: "postDate",
              weight: 100,
              direction: 'desc',
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    ],
  },
}

Queries:
http:/localhost:/api/fuzzy-search/search?query=test&filters[jobs][publishedAt][$notNull]=true&
sort[jobs][0]=isCompleted:asc&sort[jobs][1]=endDate:asc
&filters[blogs][publishedAt][$notNull]=true&filters[blogs][locale][$eq]=tr&sort[blogs][0]=postDate:desc&filters[events][publishedAt][$notNull]=true&sort[events][0]=isCompleted:desc&
sort[events][1]=deadline:desc&filters[events][locale][$eq]=tr
```